# GWT saving values from HTML form to database

Tags: forms, gwt, persistence

I am starting a new project in GWT on Jetty. I have read a lot about GWT applications and accompanying technologies. I will use GWTP as a realization of MVP pattern.
But, what with sending data from a form to database. On server side, I want to have transaction for every action. Should I use JPA or Spring? I know that in some frameworks validation of form is defined in one place, is it possible in GWT? Or maybe I have to define it in at least two places on client and then in server?

There is a lot of libraries for GWT. Are Guava, iBatis, Hibernate helpful 
for transfering data from client to server and then persisting it. What combination of libraries are you using for these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

GWT---rpc--->HIBERNATE----------->Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use any java library or framework (Spring, JPA, iBatis and ...) that fulfill your requirements on server side of your GWT application.

About validation in GWT applications, GWT has [validation mechanism](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) (based on JSR 303) and also there are several third party GWT library (e.g. [gwt-validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/)) for client side validation. In the server side you can use Java validation library. I recommend you to use both server side and client side validation.